# Is there any way to return file path like '/storage/emulated/0/Document/(list of pdf file)' with flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I want to access list of pdf files from phone local storage and show pdf thumbnails on Screen. So I decided to use `ExternalPath.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(ExternalPath.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)`  to access file path ('/storage/emulated/0/Document/(list of pdf file)') using https://pub.dev/packages/external_path package and show all of the pdf file on Screen using `ListView.builder`. But the thing is it only returns a String like '/storage/emulated/0/Document' missing '.pdf' file. How should I do this? Please help me. It have been in 1 week stuck in this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getExternalStoragePublicDirectory with ExternalPath.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS is returns file of Documents directory. You can get list of child from that directory file. Here you have to check extension of file and it is possible that directory file is available in Documents directory, which you can check using isDirectory() on File object. You can ignore or get check files in that directory too.

Look at java code sample I made for my use:

```
public void findFilesWithExtension(File sourceDir, String extension, List<File> resultFilesList, boolean checkInternalDir)
    {
        List<File> childFiles = Arrays.asList(sourceDir.listFiles());
        for (File child : childFiles)
        {
            if (child.isDirectory())
            {
                if (checkInternalDir)
                    findFilesWithExtension(child, extension, resultFilesList, checkInternalDir);
            }
            else if (child.getName().endsWith(extension))
            {
                resultFilesList.add(child);
            }
        }
    }
```